# Pagination with EclipseLink, SQL Server and spring data

Tags: sql-server, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

I am currently trying to find out what the best pagination option is with EclipseLink and SQL Server.

I saw that for SQL Server there is no special support for pagination with EclipseLink. If I have the following data model, findAll creates a set of select (n + 1) for each subentity. That doesn't look efficient at first.

```
public class Foo {
   @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
   private Set<Bar> bars = Sets.newHashSet();
}

public class Bar {
   @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
   private Set<FooBar> fooBars = Sets.newHashSet();
}

public class FooBar {
   String name;
}
```

So for every bar and fooBar there is a separate select.

Now I would like to discuss a few solutions. My current suggestions are. If a good possibility has been found, I can see how it is best implemented in spring data.

1. Chunking using Ids with IN

```
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT f.id FROM Foo f ORDER BY f.id OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 
    10 ROWS ONLY");
    List<Integer> ids = query.getResultList();
     
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT f FROM foo f"
                 + " LEFT JOIN FETCH f.bar bars "
                 + " LEFT JOIN FETCH bar.fooBars foobars "
                 + " WHERE t.id in (:ids) " )
    query.setParameter("ids", ids.subList(5, 10));
    List<Foo> foos = query.getResultList();
```

2. Using IN statement for every subselect (like hibernate) instead of single select
3. Using Batch with QueryHints IN or JOIN?
   https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/q_batch.htm
4. Another possibility?

Comment: If you need pagination support for any platform - you can extend the existing platform and override the printSQLSelectStatement method to use what you need. What you've shown is near identical to what exists in the org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DerbyPlatform class. Pagination using option 1 may help with an exact 10 entity return set, but won't help with performance; you'll need to setup test cases that mirror your average and best and worst edge cases to tell what works best for your app - generic solutions for performance never scale.

Comment: you might want to look at http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html for batch fetching discussion. You'll still need your own numbers based on your model and usecases, but it is why I recommend batch fetching instead of joining except for well known and limited ToMany relationships.

Comment: Thanks i will have a look into the blog post.